# Как получить значение options в js

Tags: javascript

Я хочу получать значение и value и содержимого options через js. С value разобрался. Подскажите как сделать чтобы брал оба значения.
https://jsfiddle.net/xoc1vbch/4/

```
<select id="myselect" class="shop__form shop__form--fixed">
                    <option value="600">.ru</option>
                    <option value="1200">.com</option>
                    <option>.su</option>
                    <option>.org</option>

                </select>

                 <div class="shop__card shop__card_price" id="mydiv">Здесь я получаю значение value</div>


                         <div class="shop__card_price" id="mydiv2">здесь я хочу получать .ru </div>






document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener("change", function () {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "" + this.value;


});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант

```
document.getElementById("myselect").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var option;
    var value;

    option = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    value = this.value;

    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = "" + value;
    document.getElementById('mydiv2').innerHTML = "" + option;


});
```